# Ruby: replace hash value with value from another hash

Tags: ruby, hash

I can't seem to figure this one out. If I have two hashes, where a value in the first hash should always match a key in the 2nd hash:

```
hash1 = { :table => 'name', :action => 'view' }
hash2 = { 'name'  => 'first_name', 'group'   => 'user_group' }
```

The key :table is a constant, but the value is dynamic. How can I swap the value in hash1 with the value in hash2, where the key matches the value in hash1? Without knowing what the actual key or value will be (other than :table in hash1)? Hope that makes sense, the updated hash1 (or new hash) should look like this:

```
hash1 = { :table => 'first_name', :action => 'view' }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see any code showing you tried to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hash1.each{|k, v| hash1[k] = hash2[v] if hash2.key?(v)}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd write (non-destructive):

```
hash3 = Hash[hash1.map { |k, v| [k, hash2.fetch(v, v)] }]
#=> {:table=>"first_name", :action=>"view"}
```

Comment: I don't know if the OP really intended this, but the question is asking to destructively modify `hash1`.

Comment: What was wrong with your `fetch`? I thought it was nice. And now, you need to assume that `hash2` does not include a `nil` or `falue` value.

Comment: @sawa: there you go, `fetch` again. I cannot seem to make up my mind whether I prefer `[k] || v` or `h.fetch(k, v)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
hash1 = { :table => 'name', :action => 'view' }
hash2 = { 'name'  => 'first_name', 'group'   => 'user_group' }

hash2.each{|k,v| hash1[hash1.key(k)] = v if hash1.has_value? k}
p hash1
# >> {:table=>"first_name", :action=>"view"}
```